# Cannot assign "'nimaaram'": "Food.user" must be a "User" instance in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Food Model just like this:

```py
class Food(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155,default='')
    colorie = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    carbohidrat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cholestrol = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fiber = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    protein = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    saturatedfat = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and i have food form just like this:

```py
class addFood(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=40,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'نام غذا'}))
    colorie = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان انرژی بر حسب کیلو کالری'}))
    carbohidrat = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان کربوهیدرات بر حسب گرم'}))
    cholestrol = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان کلسترول بر حسب میلی گرم'}))
    fat = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان چربی بر حسب گرم'}))
    fiber = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان فیبر بر حسب گرم'}))
    protein = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان پروتئین بر حسب گرم'}))
    saturatedfat = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'میزان چربی اشباع شده بر حسب گرم'}))
    def save(self,request):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        food = Food(user=request.user.username,name=data['name'],colorie=data['colorie'],carbohidrat=data['carbohidrat'],cholestrol=data['cholestrol'],fat=data['fat'],fiber=data['fiber'],protein=data['protein'],saturatedfat=data['saturatedfat'])
        food.save()
    class Meta:
        model = Food
```

and Views.py:

```py
@login_required
def addfood(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addFood(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request)
            return redirect('food:index')
    else:
        form = addFood()       
    return render(request,'addfood.html',{'form':form})
```

when i fill out form and press submit django give me 'Cannot assign "'nimaaram'": "Food.user" must be a "User" instance' error.
what should i do to fix it?
tip : request.user.username in food form is "'nimaaram'"
how i can save my form in another way?
i need user in food model fill out automatically(username)

Comment: In the save method in the form just use ```request.user``` not ```request.user.username```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user` attribute should be assigned a `User` object, not its `username`, so:

```
class addFood(forms.Form):
    
    # …
    
    def save(self,request):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        food = Food.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            name=data['name'],
            colorie=data['colorie'],
            carbohidrat=data['carbohidrat'],
            cholestrol=data['cholestrol'],
            fat=data['fat'],
            fiber=data['fiber'],
            protein=data['protein'],
            saturatedfat=data['saturatedfat']
        )
    class Meta:
        model = Food
```